# Obtaining font object from a tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

How can I obtain a font object from an existing tkinter widget? I need it to, for example, measure strings. Or I may want to create another widget with the same font, so I will pass this font object to the constructor.

The widget I am obtaining a font from may or may not have had its font set explicitly elsewhere in the program. The solution should work in either case.

Here is a small test program that shows what I am trying to do. I tried it in Python-3.4.3 on Linux. It would be good if the solution was cross-platform.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

def test():
    """ Demonstrate the ability to obtain font and use it. """
    font = myLabel.cget('font')
    print(font) # -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-*-*
    print(type(font)) # <class 'str'>
    try:
        print(font.measure('My test text.')) # fail
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # 'str' object has no attribute 'measure'
    try:
        # Try creating a new Font object from a string returned by cget('font').
        font = tkinter.font.Font(myLabel.cget('font')) # fail
        print(font.measure('My test text.'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # 'str' object has no attribute 'call'

root = tk.Tk()
myLabel = tk.Label(root, text='My Label')
myLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=20, pady=20)
root.after(1000, test)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`font.nametofont(w.cget('font'))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.font.html#tkinter.font.nametofont):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
root = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Button()
wfont = font.nametofont(w.cget('font'))
```

Comment: @mcu nametofont() returns a standard Font object, you can use it like any other Font instance.

Comment: @martineau: I only made a suggestion to help improve the answer.

Comment: This worked for me in Windows, but not in Linux, unless I explicitly assign a font to the widget first. As I suspected, `tkinter.font.nametofont()` failed to parse the cryptic `-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-*-*` returned by `w.cget('font')` in Linux. This is the error: `_tkinter.TclError: named font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-*-* does not already exist`. In Windows, `w.cget('font')` returns `TkDefaultFont`.

Comment: @mcu: Don't know what you're talking about…

Comment: I made a test on a Linux system (3.8.9), and the code output is `TkDefaultFont`.

Comment: I accept this answer because it looks like it should be a correct answer, even though it does not work for me in Linux for some reason.